# 3D tube Traversing and tooltip

Tags: 3d, geometry, three.js

I am drawing 3D tube with three.js

I am looking for implementing following functionality. Please help me for that.

1) Traversing the Pipe along the Surface
2) Placing a Marker on the Surface of the Pipe, this is like a line next to the pipe surface working as a marker.Displaying tooltip on click only on pipe which displays the actual length of pipe upto that particular point.

http://jsfiddle.net/7WNZ7/1/ `Code at above link`

Comment: hi @WestLangley please help me with above problem

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work that way here. I can't write your code for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two examples that might be helpful for you to look at:

http://jabtunes.com/labs/3d/webgl_geometry_extrude_splines.html
Click on the button "Camera Spline Animation View" and the camera will travel along the tube.

http://stemkoski.github.com/Three.js/Mouse-Tooltip.html
This code demonstrates creating "tooltips" (sprites with text).